# Environment model in init function odoo 8

Tags: odoo

I have a small doubt. I am new to odoo 8. so in my Model i use self.env['#model'] to access the specific model. Now i have around 10 different functions in my model and in each model i use model env reference to two other models. below is the code:

```
def test(self):
     location = self.env['stock.location']
     # i get values from database models

def test1(self):
     location = self.env['stock.location']
     # i get values from database models
```

Now here i need same environment in two different functions. 
Is there a way like __init__ function, which will initialize the model object and we can use it in all the functions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can just set it as a property of the class with `self` like this

```
def test(self):
     self.location_obj = self.env['stock.location']
     # i get values from database models

def test1(self):
     # You can use self.location in this method and other methods
     self.location_obj.search([('id', '=', 1)])
```

From now you can access `self.location` in any method in the class (except static methods. but you don't need that)

Comment: Thanks danidee, i will try this. is there no function like \__init__, which initialize all the object automatically

Comment: There is, but i haven't quite found a way to override the `__init__` method of odoo without causing unforseen issues. so this is the way i do it for now